# creating a tab page for a FB Pages app

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I have created a FB Pages app and am trying to figure out why my tab html is not displaying.

when I go directly to my example.com/tab url that I have set in the facebook app settings I can see the expected HTML.  When I go to my app tab on a sample facebook page I can see the request come for example.com/tab on my server as expected but nothing is displayed in the facebook page tab!

all I have is a simple

```
<div>hello world!</div>
```

and it doesn't display in the tab.  Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is it a plain html file? Have you looked in firebug what's returned from the server?

Comment: the facebook page is a mess of javascript and so I don't think it's an iframe request in the tab pane, at least I don't see any request to example.com/tab in firebug.  But I do see the request hitting my server and all I have is the above hello world code so I don't know why it's not displaying

Comment: Have you looked at network tab in firebug? Is it a plain html or you have some app server running? If it's not plain html then create a html file and link it to tab for testing.

Comment: As I stated, I can see the html if I go to example.com/tab directly.  This is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you don't have a valid SSL cert installed on your server.  Or facebook may be caching an old URL.  Check the URL it's trying to load in the iFrame to ensure Facebook is using the correct one.

Comment: I posted this question in 2010, when SSL was not a requirement.

Comment: It is now.  So maybe that might have something to do with the question still being open :)